After upgrading Azure AI Search to V11, new SearchOptions do not provide an option to specify fields count we can highlight
We recently upgraded azure ai search (acs) to version 11. We now have a new class SearchOptions.
We are not able to find the required property where we can mention no. of highlight count on a field.
Earlier it was possible through - "highlight": "description-10", where 10 returns the total highlight count of description field. By default it will be 5.
Could any of you please provide more details on same. Thank you for your help in advance.
In searchOptions class, i tried against field HighlightFields.
Ex : HighlightFields = {"Id", "Name-10"}, where id and name are column names.10 is no. of highlighted records expected. but still was returning 5.

is my solution working for you?

As per this document below is the requirement for using highlight.


Fields must be  Edm.String  or  Collection(Edm.String)
Fields must be attributed at  searchable


If not, please configure to meet the above requirements.
Next, according to this document the property of highlight should be list of strings which is similar to select and Orderby.
Like how it is given in the code similar way you add the fields.
Sample for adding select fields
            options = new SearchOptions()
            {
                Filter = "Rooms/any(r: r/BaseRate lt 100)"
            };
            options.Select.Add("HotelId");
            options.Select.Add("Description");

similarly add for highlight
options.HighlightFields.Add("Id");
options.HighlightFields.Add("Name-10");

